# Using wool curtain in gardenhouse

Tags: walls, insulation, installation, interior

We got a very nice and large piece of wool, and it would be perfect to use as a separation curtain in our small gardenhouse.

Somebody (not an expert, and not from experience) told us that somehow wool is not adapted for a garden house, it would absorb ambient water and get moldy.

I could also not find online clear explanation of the properties of wool as a curtain, and the related precaution for usage.

Our garden house is dry (no water leak inside) we are using it to sleep in summer, we are hoping to use the wool curtain to be able to also sleep warm in autumn/spring without blowing up the electricity bill. It has a small kitchen and a shower, aeration is also very good. In winter it freeze at temperature -5 C to -15 C (East of Germany)

Is it ok to use wool curtain is a garden house, what would then be the recommendations/ instructions you would give for the usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am no expert either but I would think wool will be less prone to mold and mildew than other fibers.  It wicks away moisture more than most fibers.  I have many times had cotton goods get damp in storage and get musty / mildewed, but never wool blankets or coats.

(Although moths do seem to prefer the wool.  You might have to treat it with something to keep the moths away.)

It doesn't sound to me like your garden house is a particularly dark damp environment, so I doubt it would be a problem.

Comment: In Europe, Thorlan IW is used to moth-proof wool used for insulation.

Comment: Three years later no issues indeed.